# Multiple owl carousel navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, jquery-ui-slider, owl-carousel-2

Here I'm using my owl carousel script and it's working perfectly. I'm also wanted to replicate it and used as 2nd. So, I've copied the total carousel div and changed the navigation class names to next to next2.
The carousel is working good with all options but the navigation of the replicated carousel is not working.

First Carousel:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var owl = $("#owl-demo");
        owl.owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: 10500,
            items : 6,
            itemsDesktop : [1000,6],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [900,4],
            itemsTablet: [600,1],
            itemsMobile : false,
            pagination:false,
        });
        $(".next").click(function(){
            owl.trigger('owl.next');
        });
        $(".prev").click(function(){
            owl.trigger('owl.prev');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Replicated Carousel:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var owl2 = $("#owl-demo2");
        owl2.owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: 10500,
            items : 4,
            itemsDesktop : [1000,4],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3],
            itemsTablet: [600,1],
            itemsMobile : false,
            pagination:false,

        });
        $(".next2").click(function(){
            owl2.trigger('owl.next2');
        });
        $(".prev2").click(function(){
            owl2.trigger('owl.prev2');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't understand why it's not working. Please help me someone.
Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the HTML markup of the #owl-demo2 and also the ones for the next and previous nav buttons?

Comment: Wouldn't it be: `owl2.trigger('owl2.next');` ?

Comment: I got the solution myself...

Comment: Thanks a lot for response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your slide to navigation check this snippets bellow

```js
$('.owl-navigations .right').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.'+$(this).data('slide')).trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    return false;
})

$('.owl-navigations .left').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.'+$(this).data('slide')).trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    return false;
})
```

```html
<div class="owl-navigations">
    <a href="#" data-slide="carousel-section-1" class="left">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="carousel-section-1" class="right">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <!-- items -->
</div>
```